# Custom 1-to-1 relations created by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I’m trying to get Entity Framework to create the tables in a certain way for a special 1-to-1 relation.

Let’s say I have this set of classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Child XYZ { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

The `XYZ` property of the `Parent` class MAY be set to an instance of `Child`. I would like EF to create a table for each of the two classes, and the table for `Child` objects should simply have a foreign key column, ideally named “ParentID”, to keep the relation with the `Parent` object.

I do not want a “ChildID” column in the Parent table, and I do not want to add an ID or ParentID property to the `Child` class.

Currently, the properties of the `Child` object are created as columns in the Parent table, AND I get an exception if the XYZ property is not set to an instance of a `Child` class, i.e. it can’t be null.

I’m trying to do this with the DbModelBuilder and the OnModelCreating event. The [IsOptional method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.primitivepropertyconfiguration.isoptional%28v=vs.103%29) only work with simple types.

Any suggestions? Is this even possible with EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently, the properties of the Child object are created as columns
>   in the Parent table, AND I get an exception if the XYZ property is not
>   set to an instance of a Child class, i.e. it can’t be null.

Yes it cannot be null because currently your `Child` is a complex type (value object) and it must be always set (it is part of the entity and entity doesn't exist without this part). If the content of the complex type is optional you must enforce this on Child's properties not on `Child` itself.

> I do not want to add an ID or ParentID property to the Child class.

If you want to have `Child` mapped to separate table it must have `ID` because every entity must have primary key. That ID will be also used as foreign key to `Parent` to achieve one-to-one relation:

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

And relation mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasOptional(p => p.XYZ)
            .WithRequired();
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to bite the bullet and add an ID property to my Child class. :)

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework requires 1-1 relationships to share the same primary key, which means your child must have a foreign key to the parent and that field must also be the primary key of the child.

You may not like that, but EF won't work any other way.  So either you accept it, and move on or you find a different framework.

Comment: Well, I guess I can't have it all. :) EF is pretty cool, and I should just stop wasting my time with my opinions on how it *should* create the tables.